# AppEngine TaskQueue Fires, but doesn't exist

Tags: google-app-engine

I was trying out AppEngine TaskQueues with Python. I ran some code and it created a task on the default queue, I ran the code a few more times and it created a few more tasks as expected.

I went into the Task Queue management section and manually deleted one of the tasks. All the other tasks completed ok.

I then removed the code that created the task from my AppEngine code.

But now the task I deleted keeps getting called every 20 minutes or so, is there something I can do to stop this task? It doesn't show up in any of the task queues.

I have tried disable/re-enabling the application, uploading a clean queue.yaml file.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you seeing it run in the logs, or are you seeing the effect of it running in some other way? What does the log entry look like? (Is it definitely the task-queue running it, and not someone with a browser?)

Comment: I'm seeing it run in the logs, it also does some database deletes, so I can tell when it has run. The log mentions that it was ran on the default task queue

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure this is happening, please file a  [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) with the label Component-TaskQueue and include your app ID.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the deferred modul? If so, remove the builtins: deferred from your app.yaml. Then you should make the url the task calls avaiable again and return a http-200 status code. (For the deferred-modul this is /_ah/queue/deferred). This should stop the GAE from retrying.